# For some reason, my hover captions have an extra width and height?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've set up some hover captions on my images, and they used to work perfectly. I shifted things around a bit to make room for a sidebar (it's a wordpress site), and since then I can't figure out why I have an extra 40px on the captions! I've tried changing the max width and fixed width values of the images on both WP and in my CSS. i've also tried changing the positioning and the padding and still nope. Relevant CSS below:

http://jsfiddle.net/P3ERh/

The captions just take up 100% of the width available to them, since they're contained within the post, they should take up the width of the post right? which I have defined as a max-width and max-height of 300px.

```
/* portfolio structure */

.portfoliowrapper .portfoliopost {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

.portfoliopost .post {
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

.portfoliowrapper .portfoliopost.left {
    float: left;
}

.portfoliowrapper .portfoliopost.right {
    float: right;
}

.post-thumb {
    position: relative; 
}

.portfoliopost img {
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

/* end portfolio structure */

/* caption structure */

.caption {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 300px;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

.caption p {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}

.caption p {
    bottom: 25px;
}

.caption p:last-child {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you want the caption to be contained within the `.portfoliopost img`, but it is expanding outside of that?

You might need to add `position:relative;` to `.portfoliopost img`.

Edit:

I made a few changes to your fiddle. Still a bit messy:

```
.post-thumb {
position: relative; 
max-width: 300px; /* Added */
}

.portfoliopost img {
/* max-width: 300px;*/
max-height: 300px;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
}

/* end portfolio structure */

/* caption structure */

.caption {
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
/*max-width: 300px;*/
height: 100%;
/* max-height: 300px;*/
z-index: 1000;
transition: opacity 0.25s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.25s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P3ERh/2/

Comment: You understand correctly. I tried adding that, it didn't do anything.

Comment: Yep, just made one here: http://jsfiddle.net/P3ERh/ - one of the images pokes out the top of the caption and ideally I shouldn't have to set max height and width of the caption box, it should just be set at 100%.

Comment: See my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the caption to be over the image by absolutely positioning it, you have to set the container element with relative position, so it works as a base. Else it will use other parent element as a base and will go stray.

Basically I just added:

```
.post-thumb { position: relative; }
```

To the CSS. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/gBz99/

Please, next time put the rendered html, not the php+html so we can easily put this in codepen/jsbin/jsfiddle/other right away and see what you are seeing and having trouble with. I had to substitute and assume some things in your code to try and render your problem as I couldn't really understand your issue before reading Jack's answer.

Also, you can debug this problem using your browser's developer tools. Inspect the element and see it's box model and calculated values, that way you'll know what is going wrong and where it is coming from.

Comment: Again, adding relative to the parent element had no effect. I've also created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P3ERh/) to help make it clearer. I've found a "dirty" way round and that's to set a max width and height for the caption, but as you can see, one of the images still pokes out the top of the caption box, so ideally the caption should just take 100%.